# Curious about MVC Controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Just a quick question, when you create a new controller for a new MVC ASP.Net app how does it know which controller to use. More specifically, given you create a new controller and you call it SockController in order to use said controller I would navigate to `http://mywebapp/sock`. How did the web app know that /Sock/ is linked to SockController? Is there a mapping somewhere ? Or if not what happens when if you call omit controller from the name when creating it, ie call it SockCont.

Note: I am not a Web Dev im just curious so please don't post links to page with tons of text, im looking for a short simple answer.

Comment: Default "{controller}/{action}" route takes care of mapping XXXXController to http://sample.com/XXXX route.

Comment: See also [Convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Routing extracts the name of the controller from the URL by getting the Route Value and then appending "Controller" to the end. So "/home/" returns "HomeController".

ASP.NET then uses reflection to go through every class in the project's assembly (or referenced assemblies) to find a class that inherits from System.Web.Mvc.Controller and is called "HomeController". It then uses the default, parameterless constructor to create an instance of it.

It then matches the Route action to a method of the controller.

This process is called "Dispatch" and similar patterns are seen in PHP, Ruby-on-Rails, etc, except that dynamic languages like those have different ways of resolving class names to actual objects (CakePHP uses Class auto-loading bindings to locate the class definition, for example).

Comment: Also, could you override the constructor if you really wanted to ?

Comment: Controller classes are free to implement their own controller, the only constraint is that the controller has no parameters. Hence "default constructor".

Comment: @TaylorGibb If you are using dependency injection with a custom controller factory, you can provide controllers that don't have default parameterless constructors. The default MVC controller factory will throw an error if you don't provide a parameterless constructor, though.